# Does Tapestry manage all threads inside application?

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, tapestry

Consider service, which starts some `thread` inside it. Will `Tapestry 5` manage this thread in part of e.g. closing `hibernate` sessions inside such thread or not? (For example, we can pass `Session` object inside such child-thread from service. Will `Tapestry` safely close this session after thread dies?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tapestry can only manage things declared in your AppModule.

As a simple rule, if you use the "new" keyword, it's not managed by tapestry.

If you want tapestry to manage your runnable, take a look at ParallelExecutor

If you want to mimic a tapestry managed thread, you must call Perthreadmanager.cleanup() once your runnable has finished.

Comment: The PerThreadManager service has API to assist with this.  See http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ioc/services/PerthreadManager.html#run(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate session is attached to the web container's thread which is handling the current request.

If you decide to spawn your own thread and pass to it that Session, then changes to that Session will be committed only if they 're done before Tapestry commits or before the above mentioned web container's thread ends processing that request.

Tapestry's control over the hibernate session is bound to the current request, after the request has been processed the session is closed, so spawning another thread that outlives the request to use the Session would be a bad idea.

Comment: Nothing understood. Can you answer: yes or no on my question?

Comment: There is nothing in tapestry that ties a hibernate session to a request. The hibernate session provided by tapestry is a lazy loaded, perthread value. The underlying db connection is created on demand. You just need to make sure you call perthreadmanager.cleanup if you are on a spawned thread. Tapestry calls this for you if on a request thread

Comment: The Session object is a proxy; pass the proxy to a new thread and a new, real instance for that new thread, will be created. Thus, there's no need to do that ... just inject the global Session object.